# Python: How to populate nested dict with attributes and values from parsed XML string?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dict containing identifiers as keys, with an XML string as their respective values. I want to parse the attributes and values from the XML and automagically populate a dict with them, under their respective identifier keys.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

employees = {
    'employee_0': '<Person><Attribute name="name"><Value>Bill Johnson</Value></Attribute><Attribute name="city"><Value>New York</Value></Attribute><Attribute name="email"><Value>bill.johnson@email.com</Value></Attribute></Person>', 
    'employee_1': '<Person><Attribute name="name"><Value>Amanda Philips</Value></Attribute><Attribute name="city"><Value>Los Angeles</Value></Attribute><Attribute name="email"><Value>amanda.philips@email.com</Value></Attribute></Person>'
}

for identifier_key in employees:
    xml = etree.fromstring(employees[identifier_key])
    for key in xml:
        key_str = key.attrib["name"]
        for value in key:
            value_str = value.text
            employees[identifier_key][key_str] = value_str
```

I want the `employees` dict to result in this:

```
{
    "employee_0": {
        "name": "Bill Johnson",
        "city": "New York",
        "email": "bill.johnson@email.com"
        },
    "employee_1": {
        "name": "Amanda Philips",
        "city": "Los Angeles",
        "email": "amanda.philips@email.com"
        }
}
```

But in the code above, we get a `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`. My questions are:

- Why do we get this error? It seems like this should be the proper way to populate the dict. If I instead use `employees[identifier_key] = { key_str: value_str }` it will overwrite the previous iteration. I have tried `.update()` too, without luck. How can this operation be accomplished?
- How can the operation be accomplished in a nice and clean way, e.g. using dict comprehension? I'm having difficulty putting together the syntax for it.

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
employees = {
    'employee_0': '<Person><Attribute name="name"><Value>Bill Johnson</Value></Attribute><Attribute name="city"><Value>New York</Value></Attribute><Attribute name="email"><Value>bill.johnson@email.com</Value></Attribute></Person>', 
    'employee_1': '<Person><Attribute name="name"><Value>Amanda Philips</Value></Attribute><Attribute name="city"><Value>Los Angeles</Value></Attribute><Attribute name="email"><Value>amanda.philips@email.com</Value></Attribute></Person>'
}

for identifier_key in employees:
    dic = {}
    xml = SimplifiedDoc(employees[identifier_key])
    for attr in xml.Attributes:
      dic[attr['name']]=attr.text
    employees[identifier_key]=dic

print (employees)
```

Result:

```
{'employee_0': {'name': 'Bill Johnson', 'city': 'New York', 'email': 'bill.johnson@email.com'}, 'employee_1': {'name': 'Amanda Philips', 'city': 'Los Angeles', 'email': 'amanda.philips@email.com'}}
```

Comment: Surely there has to be ways to accomplish it without importing external modules